# How to measure mental accounts of an individual?

Tags: econometrics, behavioral-economics

I wonder whether its possible to identify mental accounts as defined by Richard Thaler https://www.jstor.org/stable/183904 given i observe consumption and/ or investment behavior of an individual? I have given it some thought over the last days and one approach that i came up with is perhaps some sudden change in the marginal rate of substitution among some other things. Do you know of studies or approaches how to tackle the problem of identifying mental accounts? Thanks a lot for your feedback.